# Appending dataframe to sqlite3 table, BLOB instead of timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I am trying to append data from a pandas dataframe to existing table in a SQLite db. After the process when I try to view the data using an explorer it shows as `BLOB`. When I try to read from the database to pandas I get the error:

> Execution failed on sql 'select * from bnffut order by timestamp DESC limit 80000': not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Read the dataframe into SQLite table:

```
# the dtype of timestamp column is datetime64[ns]
query = 'insert or replace into bnffut (timestamp,close,bid,ask) values (?,?,?,?)'
conn.executemany(query, df.to_records(index=False))
conn.commit()
```

Then I try to read it into a dataframe:

```
select_statement = 'select * from '+ 'bnf' +'fut order by timestamp DESC limit 80000'
m1df = pd.read_sql(select_statement, conn)
```

1 - How to I add the data to sqlite table to make sure it is not a `BLOB` but the timestamp itself?

### Edit

I have figured out the solution to my particular problem.

The dtype is too long for a sqlite3 column, I changed the timestamp column to:

```
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].astype(str)
```

and now it shows the proper datetime and selection is not a problem.

Comment: what are you using to write your data in? sql alchemy or something else?

Comment: @Datanovice `sqlite3` and `pandas`. I am not sure if thats what you are asking?

Comment: what ORM are you using ? The reason I ask is because you can declare your `meta_types` before hand but it depends on your connection layer, with `sql alchemy` I usually make a dict of my columns and declare each type there (int,varchar etc)

Comment: @Datanovice how would I check that? I am not importing anything other than sqlite3 and pandas

Comment: hopefully that helps, I know it doesn't work with the syntax you were using but I think the sqlalchemy API is superb and should help in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

if you are able to use `sqlalchemy` then you will be able to take advantage of the `.types` class

for example :

```
from sqlalchemy.types import INTEGER, NVARCHAR, DATETIME
# on the assumption you have 3 columns, col_str, col_int, col_date
data_types_dict = {'col_str' : NVARCHAR,
                   'col_int' : INTEGER,
                   'col_date' : DATETIME}
# assuming you have your connection defined as engine
df.to_sql(con=engine,dtypes=data_types_dict,index=False,schema='dim',if_exists='append')
```

when you print your dict

```
print(data_types_dict)
{'col_str': <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.NVARCHAR'>, 
'col_int': <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.INTEGER'>, 
'col_date': <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.DATETIME'>}
```

read more about SQL Alchemy & SQL lite here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/sqlite.html

I've personally only used postgres and sql-server but from the docs it looks v.similair.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out a solution edited above. But still curious to see if a better approach exists for the question.

Comment: You should add it as an answer, but it feels like a hacky method, what is the column type in sqllite itself? if its a string you won't be able to do DateTime operations (in sql) without converting the data first.

Comment: It is hacky for sure, I am waiting for someone to give a better answer. Surprisingly the datetime operations seem to work.